# Products of distributions ill-defined

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

This question concerns distributions, as often encountered in PDE theory, which are defined as continuous linear functionals on the space $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ of test functions.

The product of two distributions, and the convolution of two distributions, is not defined in general. Are there some easy/well-known counterexamples which show why these operations cannot make sense?

Comment: Consider the following: \begin{equation}
  P_1(x)=P_2(x)=\begin{cases}
    0.1, & \text{if $0\leq x \leq 10$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then, \begin{equation}
  (P_1*P_2)(x)=\begin{cases}
    .01, & \text{if $0\leq x \leq 10$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Thus, the integral of $P_1*P_2$ over their domain does not equal 1, and it is therefore not a probability distribution function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The famous "Impossibility Result" of Laurent Schwartz precisely says:

> There is no associative algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\mathcal{D}'$ as a vector subspace and the constant function $1$ as unity element, having a differential operator acting like the differential operator on $\mathcal{D}'$ and the algebra multiplication of continuous functions is like their pointwise multiplication.

Basically the proof shows the impossibility of the coexistence of singular elements like the $\delta$-distribution, multiply continuous functions as usual, and diffentiate them like distributions.

A nice example shows that even the very simple multiplication $C^\infty \cdot \mathcal{D}', (f\cdot S)(\varphi):=S(f\varphi)$, is not associative: You have the obvious formulas
$$
1\cdot\delta = \delta, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \delta\cdot x = 0, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, x\cdot pv(\frac{1}{x}) = 1, 
$$
where $pv(\frac{1}{x})(\varphi)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\, dx$ denotes the principal value distribution. This implies
$$
0 = (\delta\cdot x)\cdot pv(\frac{1}{x}) \neq  \delta\cdot( x\cdot pv(\frac{1}{x})) = \delta\cdot 1 = \delta.
$$
So if you want to embed $\mathcal{D}'$ into an associative algebra, you necessarily need to change even the product $C^\infty\cdot\mathcal{D}'$.

This shows that you cannot define a useful product for all kind of distributions, only for some of them - basically the more singular one factor, the less must be the other ...